# ImportError: No module named test.meetinghandler

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hey friends i set my python path as

```
/home/rohit/test
```

Here is the structure  my test folder

```
test/
    __init__.py
    meetinghandler/
        __init__.py
        meetinghandler.py
    db/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        setting.py
        manage.py
```

My problem is when i am trying to import

```
from test.meetinghandler import meetinghandler
```

from  models.py 
 i am getting error i.e;

> ImportError: No module named test.meetinghandler

please help me out what i am doing wrong .

Comment: do you have `__init__.py` file inside test directory ??

Comment: i am sorry about that i could not mention that in question anyway it is there

Comment: I edited your question to include that `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`from test import meetinghandler` looks for a `test` module, which it will not find in your python path.

The reason? You added `/home/rohit/test/` to your python path, but that directory doesn't itself contain a `test` directory :-) Python looks for modules inside the path, that's why.

In your case you'd have to add your home dir to your python path to be able to find it. (Or better, google for virtualenv and so).

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging from the console.

- See if the `import test` works without error. If so, likely there is some error statement in your meetinghandler.py that is not loding the file.
- If the `import test` itself fails on the console, see if the test is in the python path (i.e, as a part of the folder that is present in the settings.INSTALLED_APPS)